# command to track the highest number of smtp login in mailexim

Tags: email, exim

Can any one help me to write a command for tracking the highest number of login in exim ?
Additionally How can I get the top authenticated smtp login in mail exim ?

Comment: What does it mean - mailexim? What do you mean saying "number of smtp login"?

Comment: edited pls check

Comment: What number do you mean? Number of all logins during period? Or some specific user's logins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't really give much detail, so here is a one liner that does exactly what you asked for (no more, no less):

```
perl -e '
  while(<>){if(/ A=(?:login|plain):(\S+) /){$found->{$1}++;}}
  @sorted=(sort {$found->{$a} <=> $found->{$b}} keys %$found);
  printf "%s: %d\n", $sorted[-1], $found->{$sorted[-1]}."\n";
' < /var/log/exim/main.log
```

It's one long line, I merely split it up for ease of readability (and to prevent the code block from rendering with a huge horizontal scroll bar).

An alternative, if you want to see all of the mailboxes and counts that are above some minimum threshold (set it to zero if you want to see all):

```
perl -e '
  $limit = 10; 
  while(<>){if(/ A=(?:login|plain):(\S+) /){$found->{$1}++;}}
  @sorted=(sort {$found->{$a} <=> $found->{$b}} keys %$found);
  foreach my $loop (@sorted) {
    printf "%s: %d\n", $loop, $found->{$loop}."\n"
      if ($found->{$loop} > $limit);
  }
' < /var/log/exim/main.log
```